# Checking if element is present using in doesn't seem to work as it should

Tags: javascript

```
>>> angular.element($0).scope().sharedData.data.ctxpf[]
["US Indexes", "Equities", "AAPL", "USI ISE Pilot", "Apple All Months"]
>>> "US Indexes" in angular.element($0).scope().sharedData.data.ctxpf["AAPL"]
false
>>> angular.element($0).scope().sharedData.data.ctxpf["AAPL"][0] === "US Indexes"
true
```

I am just checking if the string is present in the array and for a reason that I am unable to come up with - even though the string exists the comparison fails. Is there any reason why this would not work?

Thanks
Sud

**EDIT:** Much of my downfall can be attributed to trying out this and a Python-esque use of the keyword in.

```
>>> "1" in ["1", "2", "3"]
true
```

It turns out that I hadn't understood enough of how Javascript worked to gather that I was just falling into a pit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular.element($0).scope().sharedData.data.ctxpf[] is ["US Indexes", "Equities", "AAPL", "USI ISE Pilot", "Apple All Months"], so "APPL" is just a member of the array.

You can check the existence of the string as following:

> angular.element($0).scope().sharedData.data.ctxpf[].indexOf("US
>   Indexes") !== -1

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason why this would not work?

In JavaScript `x in y` is a check for the **key named `x`** in the object `y`.

It's essentially `y[x] != undefined` (but still not quite).

If you're looking for a value within an array, you should use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)